# I have predefined input fields but i want to do some operation on placeholder without changing structure of input field or adding seprate label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I have predefined input fields but i want to do some operation on placeholder without changing structure of input field or adding seperate label
please help how to deal such problem? e.g

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="applicantLastName"
    id="applicantLastName" placeholder="Applicant\'s Last Name*"
    required=""
    onkeyup="nameLengthValidation(\'applicantFirstName\',\'applicantMiddleName\',\'applicantLastName\',this)"
    lettersWithSpecialCharactersInName="true" noSpaceInBegining="true" />*
```

Comment: operations are such as adaptive placeholders.

Comment: If you mean this: `$(".input-text").prop("placeholder", "Put yer name here")` then great - otherwise: could you explain what you actually want?  Maybe add a before/after example?

Comment: can you please share your function : `nameLengthValidation` and please give some more clarity on your requirement.

Comment: i want functionality like when i start writing something in input feild the placeholder should become label.